# Windows Calculator returns wrong result

Tags: windows, calculator

if I enter 4*12+2*14 in the built-in Windows Calculator, the result is 700. Why is that?

Sorry if the question's already been asked, it's my first post.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Windows Calculator does not respect any pre-established order of operations, computing your expression from left-to-right.

In other words, your expression is treated as: `(((4*12) + 2) * 14)`

If you'd like to compute the multiplication operations and add those results, try adding parenthesis: `(4 * 12) + (2 * 14)`

Answer (score 1):

The Windows calculator performs the operations sequentially:

( ( 4 <kbd>*</kbd> 12 ) <kbd>+</kbd> 2) <kbd>*</kbd> 14 = 700

You probably want

( 4 <kbd>*</kbd> 12 ) <kbd>+</kbd> ( 2 <kbd>*</kbd> 14 ) = 76

which can be calculated with:

4 <kbd>*</kbd> 12 <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>MS</kbd>

2 <kbd>*</kbd> 14 <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>M+</kbd> <kbd>MR</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

If you switch to standard version, it does not respect operator precedence.

If you switch to **scientific version**, it DOES respect the presedence and you will get the correct answer.